# Override `render_FOO` for a related field

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have a table like that:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import MyModel

class MyTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['myfield', 'relatedtable.otherfield']
```

Since I can not have `render_relatedtable.otherfield` and `render_relatedtable__otherfield` does not work, how can I override `render_<column_name>` or `value_<colum_name>` for `relatedtable.otherfield`? Is it even possible?

---

I tried following approaches, but none of them worked:

#### Override attributes in `__init__()`

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['myfield', 'relatedtable.otherfield']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.columns['relatedtable.otherfield'].render = myrenderfnc
        # and/or
        self.columns['relatedtable.otherfield'].column.render = myrenderfnc
```

#### Custom column

```
class MyColumn(tables.Column):
    def render(self, record):
        return getattr(record, 'relatedtable.otherfield')

class MyTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['myfield']

    otherfield = MyColumn()
```

#### 'Renaming' column

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['myfield']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        exclude = ['relatedtable.otherfield']
        extra_columns = [('otherfield', self.base_columns['relatedtable.otherfield')]
        super().__init__(*args, exclude=exclude, extra_columns=extra_columns, **kwargs)
        self.columns['relatedtable.otherfield'].render = myrenderfnc
        # and/or
        self.columns['relatedtable.otherfield'].column.render = myrenderfnc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is explicitly define the column with an accessor, and then use the **column name** in your `render_FOO` method name like this:

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    otherfield = MyColumn(accessor='relatedtable.otherfield')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['myfield']

    def render_otherfield(self, record, value):
        return value
```

Your 'custom column' example example should also work though.